# xUnit.Net is not using app.manifest for longPathAware

Tags: c#, visual-studio, manifest, xunit

I am using xUnit.Net for my Unit- and Integrationtests in C#. In some tests I need to copy files or create directories. In some cases I have paths longer than MAX_PATH which is 260 characters long. To work with these paths I enabled long paths in windows as descriped [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later).

This is working fine for a console application, but not for my xUnit tests. I guess xUnit is not loading the app.manifest file because there is no .exe file. I am not sure if it is a problem with xUnit or a general problem.

Does anyone know if there is a solution for this problem? I know I could use `\\?\` as prefix to make it work but that is not really an option because of the code changes.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? IIRC .NET 4.6 and later always correctly support long paths out of the box.

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.8. I also tried it with the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` project format. With .NET 6 it is working.

Comment: Hmm... How do you run your tests? Using the console runner or using dotnet test?

Comment: I tried it with both but doesn't work.

Comment: Probably because of the xunit runner used by donet test - xunit.runner.visualstudio runs the tests in another program. Instead, use the dotnet xunit command to solve this problem.
Add the following configuration to the .csproj file of the test project:

<DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.1" />

Comment: Unfortunately does not work, but thanks for your help!

Comment: @MadMax Is there anything new about your issue?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT Not really. I have only found out that it is a general problem and has nothing to do with xUnit. I tried MsTest and get the same error there.

Comment: @MadMax It is possible that xUnit is not picking up the app.manifest file. This can happen if xUnit is not being executed as an executable with its own manifest. One solution is to add the app.manifest file to your xUnit test project and set its "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy always". This will ensure that the app.manifest file is copied to the output directory of your test project and xUnit will be able to pick it up.